# Not able to perform HTTP/S request while tethering

Tags: tethering

On my computer, I need to deactivate IPv6, deactivate all automated DNS system, set manually the DNS to any DNS I want (phone DNS or other), to be able to perform HTTP/S requests on domain names

If I don't do that, HTTP/S requests only succeed on IPv4 hostname/URL. Not on IPv6 hostname/URL or domain names (stackexchange.com etc...)

Should it be reported upstream? What is the problem?

I want to have connectivity

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to Superuser.